# En hoja de calculo de Google ¿Cómo oculto una imagen que está en una columna?

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script

Necesito que una imagen que está sobre la columna `6`, se oculte. Cuando ejecuto el código, la columna sí, se oculta, pero la imagen se mueve a la columna `7`, en vez de ocultarse con la columna `6`.

```
function TRABAJARFACEBOOK() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

    // Hides collumn (5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
    sheet.hideColumns(5);
    sheet.hideColumns(6);
    sheet.hideColumns(7);
    sheet.hideColumns(8);
    sheet.hideColumns(9);
    sheet.hideColumns(10);
    sheet.hideColumns(11);

    //unhide column L
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var rangeL = sheet.getRange("L1");
    sheet.unhideColumn(rangeL);
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene dos respuestas. ¿Te sirvió alguna de las dos?. Véase [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

La opción de menú `Insertar imagen` coloca realmente una imagen encima de una hoja de cálculo, en lugar de dentro de una celda.

El uso de la función [=IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=es) nos permite insertar una imagen dentro de una celda, utilizando la URL de la imagen.

> Sintaxis
>
> ```
> IMAGE(url; [modo]; [alto]; [ancho])
> ```
>
> - **url**: URL de la imagen, incluido el protocolo (por ejemplo, http://).
>
>   El valor de url debe ir entre comillas o ser una referencia a una celda que contenga el texto adecuado.
> - **modo** - [OPCIONAL - 1 de forma predeterminada]: Modo de ajuste de tamaño de la imagen.
>
>   1: cambia el tamaño de la imagen para que quepa dentro de la celda manteniendo la relación de aspecto.
>
>   2: estira o comprime la imagen para que quepa dentro de la celda sin tener en cuenta la relación de aspecto.
>
>   3: mantiene el tamaño original de la imagen, lo cual puede provocar que se recorte.
>
>   4: permite especificar un tamaño personalizado.
>
>   No hay ningún modo en el cual la celda cambie de tamaño para ajustarse a la imagen.
> - **alto** - [OPCIONAL]: Altura de la imagen en píxeles. modo debe valer 4 para establecer una altura personalizada.
> - **ancho** - [OPCIONAL ]: El ancho de la imagen en píxeles. modo debe valer 4 para establecer un ancho personalizado.
>
> Ejemplos de uso:
>
> ```
> IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png")
>
> IMAGE(A2;2)
>
> IMAGE(A2;4;120;200)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Como se menciona en la [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34930/65), las imágenes agregadas mediante el menú Insertar > Imagen o mediante método insertImage(blob, column, row) no forman parte del contenido de las celdas, sino que flota sobre ellas.

Actualmente Google Apps Script no tiene métodos para manejar las imágenes insertadas. Una solución es que en lugar de insertar la imágen mediante los métodos mencionados previamente, se utilice la función [IMAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34930/65) (`=IMAGE(url)`)

Nota: En lugar de usa una línea de código por cada una de las filas 5 a 11, usa una sólo línea, es más eficiente:

```
sheet.hideColumns(5,7)
```